# return the inserted element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm pretty new to jquery. I'm trying to insert an element to the DOM, and get that element back in my script.

Ex:

```
    var elem = $("body").append("");
    $(elem).show();
```

but it seems that .append returns the whole jQuery object.. 
am i supposed to use an ID for the inserted element and always reference it by it?? i really hope that there is a smarter move here.
I'm used to do it like that from Prototype..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you want to create a `div`:

```
var elem = $("div").appendTo("body").html('some html for the div').hide();
$(elem).show();
```

The above code create the `div`, sets some html for it using `html()` and hides it initially on because later you want to show it.

**Note:** Note that I have written different methods/functions on the same line, this is known as **[chaining](http://www.aspcode.net/JQuery-and-function-chaining.aspx)** in JQuery and yes very useful.

Comment: Why `.appendTo($("body"))`, why not just `.appendTo("body")`?

Comment: Novice users might benefit from your example if you add a version with everything broken up. e.g. `$div = $("div"); $div.html(".."); $("body").append($div);` what you present is what we use (+1), but it'd be confusing to someone new to jquery

Comment: doesn't $('div').appendTo("body") adds all the defined div elements in the current page back to the body?

Answer (score 0):

The `append()` method does nothing that the `$()` method couldn't do when it comes to element creation. The only difference is that `append()` adds it to the DOM.

Thus

```
$("body").append(XXXXX);
```

is no different to

```
var elem = $(XXXXX);
$("body").append(elem);
```